# Lazy loading DbSet

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I've seen people wrap `DbSet<T>` in the `Lazy<T>` class: `Lazy<DbSet<T>>`. I am only able to find one other on the internet who does [this](https://github.com/DerAlbertCom/ApereaFramework/blob/master/src/Aperea.Data.EntityFramework/Data/Repository.cs).

What is the effect of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EntityFramework internally avoids doing some of the expensive bootstrap things it needs to do on startup until it knows that it needs to. Creating the `DbContext` (among others) is one of the operations which triggers some potentially costly activities inside EF, which is (probably) why that code wraps it in `Lazy` so that if the calling code doesn't ever need to access the EF objects for whatever reason, it won't incur that cost.

This article has some useful insight into EF startup performance in various versions: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/data/hh949853.aspx

In this case (and without knowing the full context behind that GitHub code so this is largely speculation) it seems that the `DbSet` of a context is being wrapped in a separate `Repository` class, which is fairly non-standard FWIW. They've defined their DbContext as `Lazy` instantiated ([here](https://github.com/DerAlbertCom/ApereaFramework/blob/master/src/Aperea.Data.EntityFramework/Data/DatabaseContext.cs)) so they need to do the same to the `DbSet` usage to avoid eagerly resolving the `DbContext` when the repository is instantiated.

Comment: The article has left me more confused. Why do they recommend using eager loading if you don't access navigation properties often?

Answer (score 1):

In this case wrapping context in `Lazy<>` simply initializes it only until it is needed for the first time and keeps an instance available for any other operations on the repository. It's really just a simple thread-safe singleton for your DbContext.